# How do I create a while loop that will ask a user if he wants to continue and if not, it would break?

Tags: python-3.x

This program will ask a user for a unit price and quantity. It will then multiply the unit price by the quantity. If quantity is greater than 10, put in a 5% discount. If quantity is greater than 100, put in a 10% discount.

```
def bmth(unit, quan):
    def computeN(unit, quan):
        z = unit * quan
        print(z)

    if 10 <= quan < 99:
        ordercost = unit * quan
        discfive = ordercost * .05
        v = ordercost - discfive
        print('Your original price was ', ordercost)
        print('You Saved', discfive, 'off')
        print('Your new price is now ', v)
    elif quan >= 100:
        ordercost2 = unit * quan
        discten = ordercost2 * .10
        n = ordercost2 - discten
        print('Your original price was ', ordercost2)
        print('You save ', discten, 'off')
        print('Your new price is now ', n)
    else:
        computeN(unit, quan)

while True:
    unit = float(input('Enter the Unit price: '))
    quan = int(input('Enter your items: '))
    onelasttime = input('Do you wish to continue? Y or N: ')
    Y = bmth(unit, quan)
    if onelasttime:
        input(Y)
    elif onelasttime:
        input(N)
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your `while` loop:

```
while True:
    unit = float(input('Enter the Unit price: '))
    quan = int(input('Enter your items: '))
    not_continue = input('Do you wish to continue? Y or N: ') is 'N'
    bmth(unit, quan)
    if not_continue:
        break
```

Observe that:

1. `onelasttime` is a string, so `'N'` is [truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-in-python-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false) and evaluates to `True`.
2. `bmth` doesn't return, so `Y = bmth(unit, quan)` is always `None`.
3. If your `break` is not in an `if`, then `while` will break on first loop.